# Using Drupal 7 or developing a new system: What's better for a website relaunch with a community of 15.000 users?

Tags: php, python, django, drupal, html

I have to make a decision for our ([eXma](http://www.exma.info) german) community webpage. We will relauching it with a new system.

There are two sites: 
The first is to develop a whole new system on e.g. Django and Python. 
The second is to use the new Drupal 7.

Personally I have a lot more experiences with Drupal 6 and now since I'm testing Drupal 7 on my local system, I think it's a very good system with a very good API to build a growing community page with some custom module developments. 
But the other side thinks it will be better to develop a whole new system based on Django / Python (because PHP is a bad language in their mind... but I think it's never mind) because Drupal does not scale as good as a system with python (but we have only 15000 users at the moment...) and a own system is better to manage because we know the code.

Can you help me to make a good decision? I prefere Drupal 7 with some own modules, we will develop. Because Drupal has a solid core of the central modules we will need for our community.

Comment: The number of users doesn't mean much.  What traffic levels are you currently experiencing, and what are you expecting?  That will be a factor more so than number of users...

Comment: In June '10 we had a traffic of 80GB and 8 million page views. On one server at the moment. In the other months between 50 and 80GB and 5 to 8million page views per month.

Comment: So that's an overall average of 3 requests per second.  If you say that the majority of requests occur over an 8 hour period, then you're talking around 9 req/sec.  So if you plan for future expansion and overhead, you're targeting somewhere around capacity of at least 30 to 40 req/sec. That should be quite doable with whatever you choose. So performance isn't your limiting factor. Oh and in my experience the platform choice is the least of your worries. Bad Python code will be harder to scale than good PHP. Write code in the more maintainable manor, and then worry about non-existent problems.

Comment: Yes this is also my argument, that we don't really have to be worry about scaling issues in the next few years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal can be used as a very solid base upon which to build your site. It's well tested, has a variety of ready to use modules, and it is successfully [used](http://drupal.org/cases) for [busy sites](http://buytaert.net/tag/drupal-sites).

It does have a relatively steep learning curve, but the documentation and community are excellent. However you mention you do have experience with Drupal 6, so the learning curve may not be that steep for you.

On the other hand, if you feel confident about it (and even not, it will be a great learning experience), developing it from scratch yourself will definitely be more comfortable when maintaining and understanding how it works. You will be, however, rediscovering the wheel in many occasions.

Answer (score 1):

Go with what you feel comfortable with and what you feel nicer to maintain / extend.
I'd choose Python for perfomance reasons (comparing to PHP), although proper system with opcode cache can speed things up a lot.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't think there's much to gain from using Python from a performance perspective.  All my tests (with non-trivial, reasonably real world problems) show that either they are within an order of magnitude of each other, or PHP is faster (one test came out with PHP handling 10x the requests per second).  I never got Python to perform better than Lighttpd/PHP (FastCGI), and I tried I number of Python setups (FastCGI, mod_python, mod_wsgi, etc) and none was able to top PHP with FastCGI and an OP Code cache...  (Not saying it can't be done, but Python isn't in my experience faster)